# Sharing data with between Controllers with a Factory, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to share data between controllers:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return {show: true, text: "Hello"};
});

myApp.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}]);

myApp.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.click = function(){
      Data = {text:"Hello2", show:true};
    }
}]);
</script>
<body ng-app='myApp'>
<div style="background-color:red;margin-top:30px;" ng-controller="ctrl1">
    {{data.text}}
</div> 
<div style="background-color:yellow;margin-top:30px;" ng-click="click()" ng-controller="ctrl2">
    Click to change data
</div> 
</body>
```

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/QHuWLYjBqDvl20fL7eeu?p=preview . This doesn't work, however if I write

```
Data.text = 'Hello2';
Data.show = true;
```

It works perfectly. Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/xKtLUlBu0dQPUsiNCRyC?p=preview

It would be very handy to just updating a model by just specifying Json, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm afraid you linked same plnkr in both cases

Comment: @maurycy Sorry, Fixed now I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `Data = {text:"Hello2", show:true};` you completely overwrite initial `Data` object, which results into broken reference. That's why you can't just assign completely new object. You however can do it something like this:

```
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return {
        prop: {show: true, text: "Hello"}
    };
});
```

and later:

```
Data.prop = {text: "Hello2", show: true};
```

Comment: Great thought, but it seems that doesn't work either http://plnkr.co/edit/gYChWzfQ2DkwKCOuL5Zw?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZH2UKazOzogeFrJVZdLp?p=preview By writing `$scope.data = Data.prop;` you once again detach `$scope.data` from `Data.prop`. It should be however `$scope.data = Data`.

Comment: Yes, can be tricky sometimes. Read about Angular dot rule for more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
Data = {text:"Hello2", show:true};
```

You are overwriting the local `Data` variable with a new local object

When writing

```
Data.text = 'Hello2';
Data.show = true;
```

The original object that is also linked in parent scopes remains, you are overwriting variables inside the `Data` object instead of just overwriting the local `Data` link to the object